# Google Places API place_id field length

Tags: google-places-api

Google has marked the `reference` and `id` fields as deprecated as of June 24th 2014, and replaced it with a single `place_id`.

**I've so far only seen `place_id` lengths of exactly 27 characters, but wonder if there is any documentation for this length?** I have been unable to find this documented anywhere.

Obviously knowing the length of the `place_id` is significant for choosing an optimal database field, and therefore something I'd like to know.

---

*From the [Google Places API docs](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) site:*

> *The id and reference fields are deprecated as of June 24, 2014. They
>   are replaced by the new place ID, a unique identifier that can be used
>   to compare places and to retrieve information about a place. The
>   Places API currently returns a place_id in all responses, and accepts
>   a placeid in the Place Details and Place Delete requests. Soon after
>   June 24, 2015, the API will stop returning the id and reference fields
>   in responses. Some time later, the API will no longer accept the
>   reference in requests. We recommend that you update your code to use
>   the new place ID instead of id and reference as soon as possible.*

Comment: I just got an exception email from one of my systems cause the length exceeded 50 characters.

Answer (score 16):

There's no documentation on the specific length, but the max I have seen is length **255**. This corresponds to address *488 Srinagarindra Rd., Suan Luang, Bangkok, 10250*. You can check the place id [here](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id).

FYI the place id is:

`ErwBNDg4IOC4luC4meC4mSDguKjguKPguLXguJnguITguKPguLTguJnguJfguKPguYwg4LmB4LiC4Lin4LiHIOC4quC4p-C4meC4q-C4peC4p-C4hyDguYDguILguJUg4Liq4Lin4LiZ4Lir4Lil4Lin4LiHIOC4geC4o-C4uOC4h-C5gOC4l-C4nuC4oeC4q-C4suC4meC4hOC4oyAxMDI1MCDguJvguKPguLDguYDguJfguKjguYTguJfguKI`

Comment: Just had 288 characters for `33 Chaloem Phrakiat Ratchakan Thi 9 Rd, Khwaeng Nong Bon, Khet Prawe t, 10250 Khwaeng Nong Bon, TH`

Answer (score 10):

The longest I've seen so far is **315** characters. I'll update this if I find any longer.

**FormattedAddress**:
KAV.76-78, Indofood Tower, Sudirman Plaza, Jl. Jend. Sudirman No.76-78, RT.3/RW.3, Kuningan, Setia Budi, Kecamatan Setiabudi, Kota Jakarta Selatan, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10250, Indonesia

**PlaceId**:
EsIBS0FWLjc2LTc4LCBJbmRvZm9vZCBUb3dlciwgU3VkaXJtYW4gUGxhemEsIEpsLiBKZW5kLiBTdWRpcm1hbiBOby43Ni03OCwgUlQuMy9SVy4zLCBLdW5pbmdhbiwgU2V0aWEgQnVkaSwgS2VjYW1hdGFuIFNldGlhYnVkaSwgS290YSBKYWthcnRhIFNlbGF0YW4sIERhZXJhaCBLaHVzdXMgSWJ1a290YSBKYWthcnRhIDEwMjUwLCBJbmRvbmVzaWEiJRojChYKFAoSCSH20UED9GkuEc707mF-vRHxEglLQVYuNzYtNzg

Comment: If I post this formatted address you posted on google maps, it doesn't find anything.

Comment: @inafalcao You are correct. I can't seem to find it and I am no longer on that project so I can't see the data anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Although Google does not provide any explanation about the internal implementation of the place_id, it seems to be very similar to a generic GeoHash (such as ElasticSearch uses). Like GeoHashes, the place_id's lengths tend to be longer when they reference a more specific area.

The longest *place_id* I have seen so far had a length of 78, which was a specific house in large city.

Answer (score 4):

That the API does not document the length indicates that it is free to change at any time, and I would not recommend relying on a fixed length - I've seen much longer place_id's while using the API.

Answer (score 0):

The length could be event 172 chars:

```
En_QstGD0LvQuNGG0Y8g0IbQstCw0L3QsCDQkNC60ZbQvdGE0ZbRlNCy0LAsIDE1LCDQlNC90ZbQv9GA0L7MgSwg0JTQvdGW0L_RgNC-0L_QtdGC0YDQvtCy0YHRjNC60LAg0L7QsdC70LDRgdGC0YwsINCj0LrRgNCw0ZfQvdCw
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `varbinary(1024)`

Knowing possible max. length is even more important for input validation than (often prematurely) worrying about the column storage overhead. Most databases share a [similar space overhead](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings) once you exceed 255.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define the length of google place_id because in the API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=FY18-Q2-global-demandgen-paidsearchonnetworkhouseads-cs-maps_contactsal_saf&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_342758725610-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20AW%20SEM%20%7C%20BKWS%20~%20Place%20IDs%20BMM-KWID_43700042841984064-aud-596763661393:kwd-582432943155-userloc_9062139&utm_term=KW_%2Bplace%20%2Bids-ST_%2Bplace%20%2Bids&gclid=CjwKCAjwtO7qBRBQEiwAl5WC2zILVKaj9zoKpp-XVmF-TvPaoMooNM9maxER3n63p0sfXsFKRownJBoCyaoQAvD_BwE) they are not telling the max length of place_id. The only thing they are talking about is **place_id can be in a form of long string**.

I have taken field type as **TextField** in Django model.

Answer (score 0):

According the official documentation:

"A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. The length of the identifier may vary (there is no maximum length for Place IDs)"

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/place-id

So we haven't expected a string of some fixed length. We have to expect long string / text / long text